# Excel decimal rounding to QuickBooks

Tags: vba, excel, quickbooks, qbfc

I'm importing an excel sheet into Quickbooks using VBA and the Intuit API. the numbers are off by a few cents.

One number I cannot figure out.
-89.5049784337071

Quickbooks rounds it to 89.51.

I'm guessing because its a negative number. any formula or function in excel to replicate this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you recreate the issue with a truncated version of that number?  (i.e. using fewer digits)

Just wondering, as I believe Excel's floating point numbers lose accuracy after ~14 digits.  I recently experienced some similar intermittent issues due to this feature.

Comment: Excel does have a 15 digit precision with numbers, as can be viewed on their specification sheet (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx).